# How to determine which kind of datatype is use to store an integer number?

Tags: java

I want to determine for a given set of numbers which kind of datatype is use to store them.
here is my code

```
public class DataType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int num;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of inputs you want to take");
        num = input.nextInt();
        try {
        Long []test = new Long[num];
        for(int i =0;i<num;i++){
            test[i]= (long) input.nextInt();
        }


        System.out.println("output:");
        for(int i =0;i<num;i++){
            if(test[i]>=Integer.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<=Integer.MAX_VALUE && test[i]>= Byte.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Byte.MAX_VALUE  && test[i]>= Short.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Short.MAX_VALUE && test[i]>= Long.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Long.MAX_VALUE){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* short");
                System.out.println("* int");
                System.out.println("* Long");
                System.out.println("* Byte");
            }

            else if(test[i]>=Integer.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<=Integer.MAX_VALUE ){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* int");
            }

            else if(test[i]>= Byte.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Byte.MAX_VALUE  ){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* Byte");
            }

            else if(test[i]>= Short.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Short.MAX_VALUE  ){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* short");
            }

            else if(test[i]>= Long.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Long.MAX_VALUE ){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* Long");
            }

            else if(test[i]>=Integer.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<=Integer.MAX_VALUE && test[i]>= Long.MIN_VALUE && test[i]<= Long.MAX_VALUE ){
                System.out.println(test[i]+ "can be fitted in");
                System.out.println("* int");
                System.out.println("* Long");
            }

            else{
                System.out.println("Sorry!!!");
            }

        }

    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("can't be fitted in");
    }
}
}
```

input is:
5
-150
150000
1500000000
213333333333333333333333333333333333
-100000000000000
expected output:
-150 can be fitted in:
* short
* int
* long
150000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
1500000000 can be fitted in:
* int
* long
213333333333333333333333333333333333 can't be fitted anywhere.
-100000000000000 can be fitted in:
* long

but i am getting an output like this:

output:
-150can be fitted in
* int
150000can be fitted in
* int
1500000000can be fitted in
* int

Can anybody tel me why i am getting similar datatype for each integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, reading numbers like `test[i]= (long) input.nextInt();` doesn't make any sense. You are truncating long numbers to int. Judging from your test case, you need long arithmetic data type, such as `BigInteger`. `Scanner` is able to read it using `nextBigInteger()` method.

Second, your program works as expected. As you have `else if` constructions for all branches, only first matched branch will be selected. For all your test cases second branch (that check for `int`) is the first branch that matches.

If you need to match all types that can fit the current number, I suggest to introduce special data type for that purpose. Enum is the perfect candidate.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataTypeTest {

    enum DataType {
        BYTE("byte", BigInteger.valueOf(Byte.MIN_VALUE), BigInteger.valueOf(Byte.MAX_VALUE)),
        SHORT("short", BigInteger.valueOf(Short.MIN_VALUE), BigInteger.valueOf(Short.MAX_VALUE)),
        INTEGER("int", BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MIN_VALUE), BigInteger.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE)),
        LONG("long", BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MIN_VALUE), BigInteger.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));

        private final String name;
        private final BigInteger lowerBound;
        private final BigInteger upperBound;

        DataType(String name, BigInteger lowerBound, BigInteger upperBound) {
            this.name = name;
            this.lowerBound = lowerBound;
            this.upperBound = upperBound;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public boolean eligible(BigInteger number) {
            return lowerBound.compareTo(number) <= 0 && number.compareTo(upperBound) <= 0;
        }

        public static EnumSet<DataType> findAllEligible(BigInteger number) {
            EnumSet<DataType> results = EnumSet.noneOf(DataType.class);
            for (DataType dataType : values()) {
                if (dataType.eligible(number)) {
                    results.add(dataType);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of inputs you want to take");
        int num = input.nextInt();
        BigInteger [] tests  = new BigInteger [num];
        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            tests[i] = input.nextBigInteger();
        }

        for (BigInteger number : tests) {
            System.out.println(number + " can be fit in:");
            EnumSet<DataType> dataTypes = DataType.findAllEligible(number);
            if (dataTypes.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("None");
            } else {
                for (DataType type : dataTypes) {
                    System.out.println("* "  + type.getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Enter the number of inputs you want to take: 6
5 -150 150000 1500000000 213333333333333333333333333333333333 -100000000000000

5 can be fit in:
* byte
* short
* int
* long
-150 can be fit in:
* short
* int
* long
150000 can be fit in:
* int
* long
1500000000 can be fit in:
* int
* long
213333333333333333333333333333333333 can be fit in:
None
-100000000000000 can be fit in:
* long
```